# Download button under all images WordPress

Tags: posts, images, buttons

I have a WordPress site with a huge number of images and I want to add the ability to download each one. they are contained in posts (one post contains 50-100 images). I tried using the "Files Download Delay" with the search by file extension feature, but the button doesn't appear. Perhaps there is a way to combine all the images of one post into a gallery and do it with each post (the number of posts is 500) or what other ways are there to use the script given below?
how can the idea be realized? Thank you

```
jQuery(".wp-block-image").each(function() {

    var imageurl = jQuery(this).find("img").attr("src");
    var download_html =`<div class="download-link">
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" 
id="download_nopurchased" class="click_download icon-download" data- 
href="${imageurl}"  download="${imageurl}" data-url="${imageurl}"><i 
class="fas fa-download"></i> Download Now </a>
                         </div>`;
    jQuery(this).append(download_html);
});


 jQuery(".click_download").click(function() {
    var file = jQuery(this).data("url");
    var file_name = getFileName(file);
    forceDownload(file,file_name);
});

function getFileName(str) {
    return str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)
}
function forceDownload(url, fileName){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.responseType = "blob";
    xhr.onload = function(){
        var urlCreator = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var imageUrl = urlCreator.createObjectURL(this.response);
        var tag = document.createElement('a');
        tag.href = imageUrl;
        tag.download = fileName;
        document.body.appendChild(tag);
        tag.click();
        document.body.removeChild(tag);
    }
     xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: If you are using Gutenberg, you can use the filter `render_block_core/image` to add the button after the image. Alternatively, use Gallery field in Advanced Custom Fields.

Comment: @hrsetyono  Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately the gallery is not used. The pictures are just dumped in the post